# Windows Server 2008 R2 black screen with cursor at boot

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, boot

I have a strange issue with a RDS Session broker running Windows 2008R2 SP1.
I have a range of windows updates waiting to download/install:

```
KB4019263
KB4022722
KB4025337
KB4034679
KB4041083
KB4038779
KB4041090
KB4041678
KB4048960
KB4054518
KB4054521
KB4052978
KB4019108
```

There are Security Only Quality Updates for Windows Server and Security and Quality Rollups for .NET.

The .NET updates I can install without issues, but if I install even one of the Security Quality Updates and restarts the server, the only thing I get is a black screen with a mousecursor (Observed in vmware console). I can't get any remote connection to the server, not with RDP nor with registry, remote filebrowsing etc. The only response I can get is on ping.
In the winsxs folder I have a pending.xml - which I've deleted, made no difference.
Nothing is written to the eventlogs (mounted disk to another server and extracted them).
I've tested with every one of the security updates, they all result in this behaviour (install, boot, shutdown, restore, test with next update).
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to see the events with Reliability Monitor for example? https://www.howtogeek.com/222730/how-to-find-out-why-your-windows-pc-crashed-or-froze/

Answer (score 0):

The issue never got resolved, we ended up setting up a new broker instead.

Comment: Since this doesn't answer the question it would have been better to post as a comment on the question rather than as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try to delete the reg key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UFH\SHC
Hope it helps

/Ghith

Comment: This has nothing to do with Windows Update.